# How do I run Oracle sqlldr (SQL Loader) on Mac OS?

Tags: oracle, macos, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-loader

I have a seemingly simple question. How does one run sqlldr on a Mac OS X? I have researched this topic and have copied the sqlldr executable, using scp, from a remote host running the oracle server, and then installed that into the same $ORACLE_HOME/bin directory where I have a working version of the sqlplus utility. How does one go about doing this?

Comment: Does anyone know? This seems like it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

SQL*Loader now comes with the 64-bit version of Oracle Instant Client 12.2 on Mac OS. Mac OS High Sierra (10.13), Sierra (10.12) and El-Capitan (10.11) are supported.

It can be downloaded directly via the Oracle Technology Network (OTN) linked [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21105377)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - updated my answer to include all the essential information independent of the link.